# PHP Upload form to MySQL database

Tags: mysql

How do I upload simple text to my SQL database via. a PHP form?

My form looks like this: `<form action="suggestions.php" method="get">
  Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br>
  Suggestion: <input type="text" name="suggestion"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`

I have been scouting the internet for a while, but I can only find how to upload pictures, which is not what I want. I just want 2 text areas uploaded - Title and Suggestion. How do I do that?

My tables name is suggestions :)

Comment: This is really the subject of every basic PHP/mySQL tutorial out there. Hang on

Comment: This is very long winded but thorough: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up a database - for example MySQL. Then create a table. You could name it `suggestions` with 3 columns - `id`, `title`, `suggestion`. Then, you should have some code in your `suggestions.php` file responsible for handling form on submit. To insert values to database you should sanitize user input and setup a database connection(MySqli) or PDO). For example:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['title']) && !empty($_GET['suggestion'])) { // Check if variables are set.
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'yourTable'); // Connect to your database and select table, that you have created.

    if($db->connect_errno > 0){ // Check if any errors occured.
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }

    if ($stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `suggestions`(title, suggestion) VALUES (?, ?);')) { // Prepare SQL statement.
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_GET['title'], $_GET['suggestion']); // Bind values from form.
        $stmt->execute(); // Execute statement.
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
@$db=mysql_connect("server", "username", "password");
@mysql_select_db("database", $db);
if(isset($_GET)){
$sql="Insert into suggestions SET title='".$_GET['title']."' , suggestion='".$_GET['suggestion']."'";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: MySQL extension is deprecated.

Comment: Hey. It worked 50/100% I think.
It created a new url: http://localhost/Project%20Challenger/suggestions.php?title=asd&suggestion=asd

But it shows no record in the database of any values added to the columns.

I use WAMP Server with MyPhp BTW